# File or directory not found error in scrapyd-deploy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm trying to deploy my project with scrapyd-client. in my settings.py file, i defined some settings for scrapy logging:

```
LOG_FILE = 'myprojectfolder/log.txt'
LOG_ENABLED = False
LOG_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
```

but when i try to deploy this project with scrapyd-deploy command, i get this error :

```
No such file or directory: 'C:\\\\WINDOWS\\\\system32\\\\myprojectfolder\\\\log.txt'\r\n"}
```

In scrapy running, it's working fine, but in deploying, it's giving me this error.

Comment: Does `C:\\\\WINDOWS\\\\system32\\\\myprojectfolder\\\\log.txt` exist? I would say no. You have to give the correct path for your log file.

Comment: @psytho No it does not exist, if you see the log settings, the address of that file is realtive, i didnt sah it would be on c drive.  But scrapyd make a wrong address.